# Why can't I have a constructor deduce one type parameter while defining another explicitly?

Tags: templates, generics, constructor, rust

Why can't I have a constructor deduce one type parameter while defining another explicitly like this (where `A` and `B` are supposed to be distinct)?

```
struct S<A, B: Default> {
    a: A, b: B
}

impl<A, B: Default> S<A, B> {
    fn new<B>(a: A) -> Self {
        S {
            a: a,
            b: Default::default(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = S::new::<u32>(10);
}
```

This gives an error:

```
error[E0194]: type parameter `B` shadows another type parameter of the same name
 --> test.rs:6:12
  |
5 | impl<A, B: Default> S<A, B> {
  |         - first `B` declared here
6 |     fn new<B>(a: A) -> Self {
  |            ^ shadows another type parameter
```

One could rename the inner parameter (`fn new<B1>`), but then an error occurs when trying to use the constructor:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> test.rs:15:13
   |
15 |     let s = S::new::<u32>(10);
   |         -   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `B`
   |         |
   |         consider giving `s` a type
```

If `fn new` is declared without any extra parameter, an object can be created as follows, but this forces specification of both templated parameters IIUC:

```
let s = S::<i32, u32>::new(10);
```

Comment: What are you *trying* to do? Both of your examples have **3** completely independent type parameters (`A`, `B`, `B1` / the inner `B`). Why are you trying to introduce a new type parameter on the constructor at all?

Comment: @Shepmaster only because introducing another type parameter allows me to specify *what* I want to create. (Possibly the return type should be `S<A, B1>` not `Self`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you want to specify a type parameter on the function at all. Instead, you should just allow the compiler to infer the other type parameters of the struct by using `_` as the type when you construct it:

```
struct S<A, B: Default> {
    a: A, b: B
}

impl<A, B: Default> S<A, B> {
    fn new(a: A) -> Self {
        S {
            a: a,
            b: Default::default(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = S::<_, u32>::new(10);
}
```

Comment: I guess this is what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can, just not like that.

```
impl<A> S<A, ()> {
    fn new<C: Default>(a: A) -> S<A, C> {
        S {
            a: a,
            b: Default::default(),
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, it doesn't *matter* what type is used for `B`, since it's never going to be used.  It just has to satisfy the stated constraints and act as a placeholder.

I *could* have used `B` as the parameter, but I renamed it to make it clear that it isn't directly related to the type being implemented.

Comment: I believe this `impl` is only applicable to `S<A, ()>`, i.e. not generally for any `S<A, B>`?

Comment: @dhardy: So?  You're not *using* `S<A, ()>`.  `()` is only there because the `B` type parameter *has* to be set to *something*.  The compiler infers `A` from context, and you give it `B` explicitly.  It works with the example code you provided.

Comment: I see; I guess it does work. Just don't put any functions using `B` in the same `impl` block. And in examples with any type restrictions on `B`, the "dummy type" will probably have to be something other than `()`.